# Using DESC within MAX ID Sqlite3 - Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Can someone tell me why the code below is throwing errors. Its meant to look at the current id and if its less the max to descend to the next row in the database and print it.

```
def loadData(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    maxid_before = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FILMS)")
    last_row = maxid_before.fetchone()[0]
    maxid_after = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID < (last_row) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;").fetchone()
    print(maxid_after)
```

**UPDATE**
This is the function that calls loadData.What silly mistake have i done this time.You can ignore the first 5 lines or so.

```
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.edit_btn.clicked.connect(self.Retrieve)
    self.edit_save_btn.clicked.connect(self.insertData)
    last_id = 0
    if not last_id:
        connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
        c = connection.cursor()
        result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FILMS)")
        last_id = result.fetchone()[0]
    self.edit_load_btn.clicked.connect(self.loadData)
```

And this is the loadData function

```
def loadData(self, last_id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    maxid_after = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;", (last_id,)).fetchone()
    print(maxid_after)
    return maxid_after
```

Comment: *What* errors does it throw?

Comment: operational error: no such column last_row.

Comment: And what is `last_row` supposed to be?

Comment: its supposed to represent the current id number. this function is connected to a button event. Once clicked it prints the next row in the database.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "current" here. In what sense? Current according to what?

Comment: theres 4 columns in my table(id,title,year and rating). i have a gui form where you enter these details and save it to the database.The next time you return i want to press the button and it will print the last data entry/row and once pressed again prints the one before that. So what i mean by current is the program gets the maximum id (the last data entry), and from there descends on button click. I hope that made sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
maxid_after = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;", (last_row,)).fetchone()
```

In your code `last_row` is a variable not column name. So, you should put the value of `last_row` in the query.

If you put `last_row` in the query like you did, sqlite will treat `last_row` as a column name and try to execute the query like that. As it fails to find any column by that name, it throws the error.

If you want to run this function on a button click and return one by one row in descending order in every button click, then your function should be like this -

```
def loadData(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID < ? ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;", (last_id,)).fetchone()
    if result:
        self.last_id = result[0]
    connection.close()
```

And the function that calls `loadData()` should be like -

```
# This is the code that calls loadData()
# This is __init__

result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FILMS)").fetchone()

if result:
    self.last_id = result[0]

...
# On button click
# Call loadData
```

Comment: Thanks this stopped the error but the programs keeps printing the last_row and not the query you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. It prints the value you want right? Can you show me the result it prints with modified code?

Comment: (3, 'The Dark Knight\xa0 ', '(2008)', 9)

Comment: If this function is getting called by a button click and you want the value in decending order, then you should move the first query to the calling function and pass the last id as parameter to this function. after this function returns you should update that last id variable

Comment: when i press the button again , i want it to print (2,'Inception\xao','2008',8.8) which is the row before the one i just sent

Comment: Yes. I got that. Try the way I said in the previous comment

Comment: Could you show me how that looks please, im new to sqlite and ive been stuck on this for days

Comment: could you check out my update , im so sorry for wasting your time , im trying my best to make it work.

Comment: @Noob, can you make `last_id` an object variable? Then you can just set `self.last_id` from `loadData()` instead of returning it and also you don't have to pass `last_id` in `loadData()`. also remember to close database after you are done

Comment: im so sorry for sounding like a noob but i honestly have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Is the class defined by you? Then use `self.last_id` instead of `last_id` in `__init__` as well as `loadData()`. Also change `c.execute(..` to `self.last_id = c.execute(...` in `loadData()`. See my update

Comment: OMG thank you so much you dont understand how much this means to me.Ive been struggling with this for days.

Comment: for the opposite would i replace the desc with asc? what other changes would i need to do? any sign changes?

Comment: Apart from changing  it to `ASC` you should also change `<` to `>`. Also `MAX` should be changed to `MIN` as well

Comment: Thank you so much i think im done now , i really appreciate all your help

Comment: @Noob, you are welcome. I suggest using sqlite3 cli to make yourself acquainted with sqlite. Then you will be very easily able to apply that  knowledge in python program as well. Anyway, good luck on your programming journey